# Notifying Friends When New Friend Joined?

Tags: notification, alerts, connection

What seems like the proper way to notify friends that a new friend has joined. Pros and cons for each scenario from experience would be helpful, from a UX perspective I'm interesting and seeing which one can lead to higher user growth and connection without scaring users away.

---

## Scenario 1:

**User A** signs up and allows app to view contacts for possible friends. **Friend B**, **Friend C**, and **Friend D** don't have an account so no friends are suggested. However, their phone numbers are uploaded to the cloud.

When **Friend B** signs up the following week, and also allows access to her contacts. Although she doesn't have **Friend A** in her contacts, she does have **Friend C** and **Friend D**. She adds **Friend C**, but not **Friend D**.

**Friend A** wasn't shown bc it's not in the current user's (**User B's**) contacts.
**Friend C** has now been friended by the current User (**User B**).
**Friend D** was ignored.

Should **Friend A** be notified that **Friend B** just signed up, since **Friend B** never had the option to add them? Should **Friend D** NOT receive a notification since **Friend B** actively did not add them?

---

## Scenario 2:

**User B** signs up but doesn't give access to her contacts, therefore no friend suggestions are made. However, 2 months ago when **User A** and **User C** made accounts their contacts were synced to the server. In their contacts was **User B's** number. Should we query for all User's with **User B's** number (we have this bc of a verification step) and send a push notification to **User A** and **User C** that **User B** just joined? Or is this weird for **User B**, since they didn't provide access to their contacts?

---

## Scenario 3:

Assuming that **User B** allowed access to contacts, don't sync any of them to the server. Instead, returns list of users whose number appears in **User B's** contacts, and show a add friend list. For all users who **User B** adds send them a friend request push notification, and for those she didn't add, send them an alert that **User B** (someone they might know, has just joined).

Answer (score 1):

I kind of get the "LinkedIn" mood here!

Some of the scenarios mentioned are working for LinkedIn: 
What they do is to make the difference between User 1, who reaches out to contacts and User 2 who reaches out for himself.

This means, even if User 1 denied contact access while signing up, User 2 will still be recommended to connect to User 1 if he is in User 2's contacts.

So User 1 cannot express a "general dislike" of being connected. The question is only about "Do YOU want to contact people", which makes perfect sense to me, since it is a social network - and if I could erase my presence for everyone by saying "no", I'd break the business case.

I'd assume (but I did not prove that yet) that the greatest friction is created if I, as a non registered user, am confronted by a mail that tells me "join my network!" since these users did not have any motivation at all.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 3 looks reasonable, with one note. We should only alert those non-added users, who previously show they know User B (having him in their shared contacts).

Another idea: when there are not so much users in the service and therefore a little friends, we can be more active notifying about possible friends. But when there are too much new users coming, we probably should mute friend suggesting spam.